# Drupal and Gmap markers for countries

Tags: drupal, drupal-gmap

I'm using Drupal 6 along with Gmap module.
For some search functionalities, which I would like to implement using Gmap, I need to have markers for some countries presented on a map.

For example, on front page, I want to display world map with markers for UK, Ireland and New Zealand.
Is there a way to somehow achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you would like to achieve, but with the [Location module](http://drupal.org/project/location) you could associate Location data with nodes and later use that data for displaying on a Gmap (for example in a view). The Location module provides a Location field that you can use in your own content types.

I did the same for displaying user locations with the same toolkit and it's working well.